# Issue with sending model object in json response laravel 5.6.12

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel-5.6

Laravel 5.6.12

I am trying to get database model

```
$data = \App\Data::all();
return response()->json(
["data" => $data]);
```

and sending it to JavaScript learned from there [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#json-responses)

Now I want to get specific data from model object. I received it by JavaScript(jQuery) ajax. On success I recieved it. But I have to convert it into string using JSON.Stringify() and when I try to display it give me this data

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"name":"Ibrahim","fatherName":"Ahmed","created_at":"2018-04-05 04:02:31","updated_at":"2018-04-05 04:02:31"},{"id":2,"name":"Haris","fatherName":"Shabir","created_at":"2018-04-05 04:02:31","updated_at":"2018-04-05 04:02:31"}]}
```

I just need to know what type data format return response()->json() and why I need it to convert it to string and how can I access the only all the names in details. There is two rows in database model and there can be more.
I put the output format on the fiddle for to access all the names [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ibrahim_7/acrhwsok/16/)

Ajax

```
  function ajax(event) {
        var x = "";
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: " {{ route('ajax') }}",
            data: {_token: "{{ Session::token() }}"},
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success : function (data) {
            if (data)
                {
                    data2 = JSON.stringify(data);
                     $("#demo").html(data2); // this give above whole output
                }

            },
            error: function (xhr,ajaxOp,errors) {
                $("#demo").html(errors);
            }
        });
    }
```

This is ajax

Comment: show your ajax code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all of the users, you'll need to loop over the array;

e.g.

```
var data = {"data":[{"id":1,"name":"Ibrahim","fatherName":"Ahmed","created_at":"2018-04-05 04:02:31","updated_at":"2018-04-05 04:02:31"},{"id":2,"name":"Haris","fatherName":"Shabir","created_at":"2018-04-05 04:02:31","updated_at":"2018-04-05 04:02:31"}]};


var users = "";

for(i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) { 
    users += data.data[i].name + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("done").innerHTML = users;
```

Using your example you could try;

```
<script>
    function ajax(event) {
        var x = "";
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: " {{ route('ajax') }}",
            data: {_token: "{{ Session::token() }}"},
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success : function (data) {
                if (data)
                {
                    var users = '';

                    for(i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                        users += data.data[i].name + "<br>";
                    }

                    $("#demo").html(users); // this give above whole output
                }

            },
            error: function (xhr,ajaxOp,errors) {
                $("#demo").html(errors);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

You shouldn't need to stringify the data.

Comment: Your answer is correct and its working but why its not working in my ajax function please see my code what I am doing wrong with it.

Comment: @Ibrahim I've updated the answer for you - hopefully that will help.